# Count the number of files in a folder that have certain strings

Tags: python-2.7, count, text-files

I have a folder with 200 files. Each file has data like

VISITERM_90 VISITERM_0 VISITERM_34 ..... etc.

Each file does not have the same elements. So, I would like to count the number of files which have the elements from VISITERM_0 to VISITERM_99. That is I should get my output as:

> VISITERM_0  200
>
> VISTERM_1   140
>
> VISITERM_2  150

and so on depending upon the numbers of files that has the specified elements. I want to run it in a loop from VISITERM_0 till VISITERM_99 and for each element I need to find the number of files.

My code is:

```
import os
vt = 'VISITERM_'
no = 0

while no < 10:
    for doc in os.listdir('/home/krupa/Krupa/Mirellas_Image_Annotation_Data/Test/sample_codes/Files'):
        doc2 = '/home/krupa/Krupa/Mirellas_Image_Annotation_Data/Test/sample_codes/Files/' + doc
        c = vt + (repr(no)) 
    
        with open (doc2, 'r') as inF:
                    
            for line in inF:            
                if c in line:
                    print c, doc2
                
                else:
                    print "DOES NOT EXIST" , c, doc2
    no = no + 1
```

This code is printing me each visiterm and each of the file that has it. I just want the VISITERMS_* and their corresponding number of files. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My python skills are a bit rusty, so bear with me. I think that you need a way to store the values while looping, I'll use a dictionary. This is not the complete solution, but it can help you figure out what you need to do:

```
dict={}
for doc in os.listdir('..'):
    doc2 = '..'
    with open (doc2, 'r') as inF:
        for line in inF:
            while no < 10:
                c = vt + (repr(no)) 
                if c in line:
                    numberOfElements = 0
                    if dict.has_key(c):
                        numberOfElements = dict[c]
                        numberOfElements += 1
                    else:
                        numberOfElements = 1
                    dict[c] = numberOfElements
                no += 1

for key in dict.keys():
    print key, dict[key]
```